# asp c# send email without configuring sender credentials

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to test sending out emails to users from a generic email such as noreply@company.com.
I want to do this in a button click event. How do I achieve this without using credentials?
I have tried several things but I always get errors.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mm.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("Email Address", "Name"));
        mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("Email Address");
        mm.Sender = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("Email Address", "Name");
        mm.Subject = "This is Test Email";
        mm.Body = "<h3>This is Testing SMTP Mail Send By Me</h3>";
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High; // Set Priority to sending mail
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtCliend = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        smtCliend.Host = "Your smtp server";
        smtCliend.Port = 25;    // SMTP port no            
        smtCliend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User Name", "Password");
        smtCliend.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        try
        {
            smtCliend.Send(mm);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "\n\n\n" + exe.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your SMTP server require credentials?  This line is probably causing issues if those are not your actual SMTP credentials: `smtCliend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User Name", "Password");`

Comment: no this is just the template I used. I want a way to not using the credentials. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try to set the `UseDefaultCredentials` flag to false and omit your line above that sets credentials: `smtCliend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User Name", "Password");`.  Of course, this all assumes that the values in your actual code are set to the correct values and not the placeholders seen above.